# Does Grub2 support Memtest86+ iso files?

Tags: grub2, memtest86+

Does Grub2 support Memtest86+ iso files? If it's supported: How could I write a grub entry in grub.cfg in order to boot the Memtest86+ iso file?

Comment: Grub doesn't support ISOs natively. Typical solution is to use GRUB to load a Linux install and use it's CDROM driver to load the ISO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways of adding ISO's to grub2 configurations.  It is easier to use other options, however.

1. Download [memtest86+-4.20.bin](http://memtest.org/download/4.20/memtest86+-4.20.bin) (Latest as of 11/2011)
2. Place it in your /boot partition. (Just like your Linux kernels)
3. Add the following to /etc/grub.d/40_custom (It should be on three lines, like [this](http://pastie.org/private/iqkom7nff0a6zrcvykhhg))

> ```
> menuentry "Memtest 86+" { 
> linux16 /memtest86+.bin
> }
> ```

Final. Update your grub and reboot

```
sudo grubupdate && sudo reboot
```

Comment: gparted (which is something else you may want to have as a boot option) has a detailed explanation of how to add Grub2 menu entries of many of it's available builds (iso, vmlinux).

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livehd.php

Answer (score 3):

Six years late to this party, but seeing as I couldn't find the answer anywhere either, here's what I did to work it out.

- Mount the memtest ISO
- Look at *mount-point*/isolinux/isolinux.cfg
- Convert isolinux config to GRUB2 config

Note that that method works for other ISOs, not just Memtest86+.

Doing the above yields multiple isolinux configs depending on how you want to start Memtest86+, so you end up with multiple menuentries:

```
submenu "> MemTest86+ 7.2" {
    menuentry "MemTest86" {
        set isofile="/Memtest86-7.2.iso"
        echo "Mounting Memtest86-7.2.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        echo "Loading kernel"
        linux16 (loop)/isolinux/memtest iso-scan/filename=$isofile
        echo "Starting MemTest86+ 7.2"
    }

    menuentry "MemTest86 (one pass)" {
        set isofile="/Memtest86-7.2.iso"
        echo "Mounting Memtest86-7.2.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        echo "Loading kernel"
        linux16 (loop)/isolinux/memtest iso-scan/filename=$isofile onepass
        echo "Starting MemTest86+ 7.2"
    }

    menuentry "MemTest86 (btrace)" {
        set isofile="/Memtest86-7.2.iso"
        echo "Mounting Memtest86-7.2.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        echo "Loading kernel"
        linux16 (loop)/isolinux/memtest iso-scan/filename=$isofile btrace
        echo "Starting MemTest86+ 7.2"
    }

    menuentry "MemTest86 (single CPU)" {
        set isofile="/Memtest86-7.2.iso"
        echo "Mounting Memtest86-7.2.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        echo "Loading kernel"
        linux16 (loop)/isolinux/memtest iso-scan/filename=$isofile maxcpus=1
        echo "Starting MemTest86+ 7.2"
    }

    menuentry "MemTest86 (serial output)" {
        set isofile="/Memtest86-7.2.iso"
        echo "Mounting Memtest86-7.2.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        echo "Loading kernel"
        linux16 (loop)/isolinux/memtest iso-scan/filename=$isofile console=ttyS0,9600
        echo "Starting MemTest86+ 7.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man. That is not late, that was very helpful, just right in present moment! ;-)